# Is there a "list of installed programs"?

Tags: software-installation, users, software-sources, installed-programs

Back when I mainly used Windows, I always exported a text file containing my installed programs from the software "CCleaner" before reinstalling my operating system, so that I had a list with all the software I would have to reinstall and not miss anything.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find such a list in Ubuntu (using Xfce currently, but also just in general). Also, it would be helpful if that list did not include just all packages, such as plymouth, gedit and nautilus, which are installed by defauly anyway, but only those installed by the user.

Is there a way to obtain such a list?

Comment: `comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)` from the liked answer seems to do the trick. Thank you for the hint and sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [aptik](https://www.tecmint.com/aptik-a-tool-to-backuprestore-your-favourite-ppas-and-apps-in-ubuntu/) to back up and reinstall a list of your programs. As well as ppas, and other useful functions.

The list is stored as text so you can inspect it as you wish. The program also characterizes the programs by type.  It is a useful tool IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the package [Aptik](http://www.noobslab.com/2017/05/aptik-let-you-organize-your-favorite.html) to backup everyting. So that you can restore every single package and PPAs and other settings after upgrading distro or move to different debian or Ubuntu based distro.

use following commands for install Aptik`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa`
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package aptik

Answer (score 0):

It is way too hard what is work as well as that Windows option you are talking about go to software centre > installed softwares then there's you can find all the softwares that you currently have installed on your PC and take a note of it if you want to re install. install  it from there or use the Sudo apt-get install command